# JQuery play sound file in Mac OS X Safari does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, html5-audio

I am trying to play an mp3 file with JQuery or Javascript, but it does not work in Safari on Mac OS X. Tried the following options:

HTML

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/scripts/sound/sound.mp3"></audio>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_audio").get(0).play();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_audio").prop('play');
});

var x = document.getElementById("my_audio"); 
x.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2650714) Apple Support question, it seems you need to use mpeg file type.
Check if your page has doctype html, as Safari is known to not render HTML-5 content without the proper DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

If all your audio files are `mp3`, you can simply add the audio file type attribute like this:

```
<audio id="my_audio" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/scripts/sound/sound.mp3"> type="audio/mpeg"</audio>
```